# get the value of href using lxml in html table

Tags: python, html, lxml

I have a html table.
in that table I have

```
<td>abc</td><a>www.abc.com</a>
```

how can I get the link value using matching the value of td?

for example : how can I get the value of www.abc.com searching the tect abc using lxml?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`a/text()` to get text

`a/@href` to get attr (`href` in this case)

**UPD**

```
>>> from lxml import etree
>>> etree.fromstring('<html><td>abc</td><a>www.abc.com</a></html>').xpath("//td/following-sibling::a/text()")
['www.abc.com']
```

[XPath 1.0](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/)

Comment: yes but how i will get the www.abc.com by searching abc?
doc.xpath('/a/text()') I have add something to this to get the link of same text?